# Nested SVG image skips the render of next elements

Tags: svg

I am having issue with nested SVGs images.

The follow code display 3 things: a background and 2 items.

```
  <div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1280 720" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <image class="BACKGROUND" xlink:href="bg.png"
        height="775" width="1462" y="0" x="0"></image>
      <svg class="ITEM1" width="226" height="247" x="893" y="6">
        <image xlink:href="logo.png"
          height="247" width="226" y="0" x="0"></image>
      </svg>
      <svg class="ITEM2" width="616" height="70" x="106" y="27">
        <text y="0" x="0">Proposition commerciale</text>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

While ITEM1 (Renault logo) is visible, ITEM2 (the slide title) is hidden:
[image: only ITEM1 visible]

If I have N items after ITEM1, all of them would be hidden.
If I place ITEM2 before ITEM1 on the DOM, ITEM2 is visible:

[image: both ITEM1 and ITEM2 are visible]

When I play with DevTool and changing an attribute of ITEM2, it appears until I move the cursor out.

Any idea what's going on? Is that a bug or am I doing something I should not?

Comment: BTW just realized it works on Chrome 87 but not on Firefox 84. Sounds like a bug then

Comment: It was a bug but I already fixed it. The fix will be part of Firefox 86. You should be able to test that in [Beta already](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/channel/desktop/) if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick: wrapping the `<image>` into a `<g>` with a `translate(0,0)`.

```
 <svg class="ITEM1" width="226" height="247" x="893" y="6">
    <g transform="translate(0,0)">
      <image xlink:href="logo.png"
        height="247" width="226" y="0" x="0"></image>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

This bypass the issue on Firefox